# WPF- List View. How can I enable my content to display Vertically and Horizontally?

Tags: wpf, listview

I'd really appreciate some help in regards to this. So I have a List View on my Home page and at the moment all the content is displayed Vertically. One underneath the other. The content is comprised of an Icon, Title and Description. This content is loaded dynamically at run time.
I would like the content to be displayed in a different way so that I have it displayed like

Content        Content

Content        Content

Content        Content

Content        Content

I am unable to change from a listview so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been able to have the content display horizontally but not both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: By default, `ListView` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`  So you should set the `ItemsPanel` property to use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UniformGrid with two columns:

```xml
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```